# How to find out if char is number in JAVA, ONLY with string methods?

Tags: java

I need to find out how can I check if a char is a number. The problem is that I can't use any methods except string methods like IndexOf, SubString, length, charAt.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why not just Character.isDigit()?

Comment: Why can u only use string methods?

Comment: I don't know no Java but I'm quite sure there are several ways to do it... testing ASCII code, using out of the box functions to identify digits, testing successively with indexOf('0'), indexOf('1'),... you should try yourself to do what looks like a homework

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "number" ... or even "digit".  If you are talking about the ASCII digits '0' through '9', the solution is easy.  If you are talking about digits / numbers more generally, it ain't.

Answer (score 3):

If it has to be String methods:

```
    String n = "0123456789";
    char c = 'a'; // As I don't know where your char will come from and in what format

    int i = n.indexOf(c);
    if(i != -1) {
        System.out.println("Digit");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Not digit");
    }
```

But I can't stress enough that this is, well, idiotic and pointless from my point of view.

Comment: And that's downvoted because...? Didn't I state that I find both this exercise and solution useless?

Comment: Read the question, you are not answering it.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking Yes, I do. We might understand it differently, but doesn't mean that's me who got it wrong.

Comment: @Apédémak seriously? read the question, read the answer, then ask your own questions, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Character.isDigit()` for this.

If you have a string, you can do this :

```
Character.isDigit(yourString.charAt(index));
```

And withtout any Character method you can use Regex :

```
s.substring(startIndex,endIndex).matches("[0-9]")
```

Comment: I can't use any methods except string methods as I mentioned before.

Comment: Still using the String methods that are not allowed.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking His needed was to use only string methods. And that's what the second code do.

Comment: can't use regex also, it's a stupid question I agree, but it's needed for exam

Answer (score 0):

**You can check the character for its UNICODE value:**

```
char c = string.indexOf(...); // or other way to get the character

public static boolean isDigit(char c) {
    return c => '0' || c <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below based on the **ASCII** values comparison:-

```
    String s = "123456ao";
    char[] ss = s.toCharArray();
    int intVal = 0;
    for( char s1 : ss){
        intVal = s1;
        if(48 <= intVal && intVal < 58) // checking for ASCII values of numbers
            System.out.println(s1+ " is Numeric");
            else System.out.println(s1+ " is not Numeric");

    }
```